# Amazon Web Service (AWS): Spot request active followed by cancelled terminating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
5/31/2018, 5:21:51 PM   fleetRequestChange  cancelled
5/31/2018, 5:15:46 PM   fleetRequestChange  cancelled_terminating       
5/31/2018, 5:15:46 PM   fleetRequestChange  active      
5/31/2018, 5:15:36 PM   fleetRequestChange  submitted
```

I am trying to create a Spot instance. However, it's cancelled right after it's being activated. Tried several times.

What is the problem??

Comment: Verify that the instance would not cause you to exceed your limit for that instance type in the region.  Find the `Limits` link in the console.

Comment: Running On-Demand EC2 instances: 1

Well.. the error message could be more precise then. Just cancelling the service without notice why isn't the best solution I guess...

Comment: One problem is that spot fulfillment is asynchronous.  If you requested on-demand instances that exceeded your allowed capacity, the error would be immediate and explain the problem, and not deferred like you see here.  Spot has services talking to services on your behalf; in some cases would a limit exceeded make the spot request impossible to fulfill, in others it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the initial limit for instances is set to 1. Solution is to request a limit increase which is not intuitive by the provided instance cancellation.

[AWS Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html)

> You can take the following steps to request an increase for limits.
>   These increases are not granted immediately, so it may take a couple
>   of days for your increase to become effective.
>
> To request a limit increase
>
> Open the AWS Support Center page, sign in if necessary, and choose
>   Create Case.
>
> For Regarding, choose Service Limit Increase.
>
> Complete Limit Type, Use Case Description, and Contact method. If this
>   request is urgent, choose Phone as the method of contact instead of
>   Web.
>
> Choose Submit.